How might I optimize computing a large bilinear function exhibiting more-or-less random access?
I have a function which takes two arrays and fills a third array with bilinear combinations of the coordinates of the two arrays. The function is a clifford product over an 8-dimensional real vector space, in case you're curious.
To make this as fast as possible, I pre-computed the indices of the "access patterns" needed to define the product. Each access pattern is an unsigned 32-bit integer. Here's an example access pattern:
00001100.00000100.00001000.00000001
Assuming that the input arrays are arr1 and arr2, and that the output array is ret, here's what this pattern means:
ret[00001100] += arr1[00000100] * arr2[00001000] * (-1)^00000001;

The (-1)^s term isn't actually computed. Instead, I just branch on the whether or not the last 8 bits are 0. A non-zero value indicates a -= instead of a +=. Some bits are wasted, but it seems worthwhile to have a 32-bit pattern.
The access patterns are stored in a big sorted array. Writes are bundled together, so I only need to access ret[i] once per block - presumably, this improves cache locality by letting the CPU accumulate everything it needs from arr1 and arr2 before writing out to memory. Said differently, instead of doing:
ret[i] += arr1[j]*arr2[k]*(-1)^s;
ret[i] += arr1[j']*arr2[k']*(-1)^s';
...

I do:
float x = 0.0;
x += arr1[j]*arr2[k]*(-1)^s;
x += arr1[j']*arr2[k']*(-1)^s';
...
ret[i] += x;

Once per iteration over blocks with constant i.
In the above, the access patterns are: (i,j,k,s), (i,j',k',s'),... When i changes, I move to the next iteration.
I'd like to take advantage of SIMD and instruction-level parallelism. Here's how I think that would look:
For ILP, add more intermediate variables:
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;
x += arr1[j]*arr2[k]*(-1)^s;
y += arr1[j']*arr2[k']*(-1)^s';
x += arr1[j'']*arr2[k'']*(-1)^s'';
y += arr1[j''']*arr2[k''']*(-1)^s''';
...
ret[i] += x + y;

I'm just taking more access patterns per iteration, and I'm trying to convince the CPU to modify x and y in parallel. Adding SIMD to this would entail taking more access patterns per  iteration, I think, but this is as far as I've gotten. Before I start diving into SIMD operations, please help guide me onto the right track. What should I be aware of when writing a function like this, and how can I make it as fast as possible?
EDIT: More Detail
I'm writing a toolkit for 3D geometry. The idea is to minimize the time and space needed to do things like apply an isometry to an object in 3D space or detect intersections, halvings, etc.
The horrible 130,000-element access pattern is the result of multiplying elements of the "top type", which is the exterior algebra over the direct sum of R^4 and its dual (this ends up being similar to a direct sum over all spaces of antisymmetric tensors on R^4). The reason for more than 256*256 access patterns is that the metric I'm using is slightly non-orthogonal. The extra elements come from applications of the distributive property when pre-computing products.
I will not use the top type in applications, but it's useful in testing since smaller types naturally embed into the top type. The smaller types will probably end up using custom code instead of this access pattern function, but the presence of the top type gives me something to compare custom code to.
Normally, I'd orthonormalize the basis, which would halve the number of access patterns in this case. The reason that I don't do this is that most of the work will be done using much smaller types, like forms, vectors, bivectors, etc. Locally, these smaller types enjoy orthogonal bases, and I want to preserve that.
Originally, instead of generating access patterns, I generated code directly. This produced very fast results until I finally broke my compiler (blew the heap compiling the product on the top type). I went to all this trouble so that I could unroll the loops defining things like the wedge product, left interior product, and Clifford product. The tradeoff was speed vs code size. Once the code size became too large, I changed strategies: make one function that reads access patterns, and maybe some metadata like block divisions, to compute the product. It's kind of like a bytecode representation of a bilinear operator. My runtime speed halved, but my compilation time dropped from an hour (and maybe failing) to a minute.
To give you an idea of where I'm at, the old hard-coded wedge product on the top type (256 coordinates) computed at about 4,000 Operations Per Frame (4,000 worst-case wedge products per 1/60th of a second). On vectors, I had 700,000 OPF. This was just naive array assignments, one after another with all indices filled in.
The access pattern method for defining the wedge product yields about 2,000 OPF for the top type and 417,000 OPF for vectors. Here's what the new method looks like:
(defun calculate-product (access-patterns blocks numblocks arr1 arr2 retarr)
  (declare (type (simple-array access-pattern) access-patterns)
           (type (simple-array (unsigned-byte 32)) blocks)
           (type fixnum numblocks)
           (type (simple-array scalar) arr1 arr2 retarr))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (dotimes (write-index numblocks)
    (declare (type fixnum write-index))
    (let ((acc +zero))
      (declare (type scalar acc))
      (loop for j from (aref blocks write-index) below (aref blocks (+ write-index 1)) do
        (let* ((access-pattern (aref access-patterns j))
               (sign (ldb (byte 8 0) access-pattern))
               (read-index-2 (ldb (byte 8 8) access-pattern))
               (read-index-1 (ldb (byte 8 16) access-pattern)))
          (if (zerop sign)
              (incf acc
                    (* (aref arr1 read-index-1)
                       (aref arr2 read-index-2)))
              (decf acc
                    (* (aref arr1 read-index-1)
                       (aref arr2 read-index-2))))))
      (incf (aref retarr write-index) acc)))
  nil)

Here is the disassembly:
; disassembly for CALCULATE-PRODUCT
; Size: 192 bytes. Origin: #x24984E22                         ; CALCULATE-PRODUCT
; 22:       41844424F8       TEST AL, [R12-8]                 ; safepoint
; 27:       31F6             XOR ESI, ESI
; 29:       E985000000       JMP L4
; 2E:       6690             NOP
; 30: L0:   0F57C9           XORPS XMM1, XMM1
; 33:       418B547301       MOV EDX, [R11+RSI*2+1]
; 38:       48D1E2           SHL RDX, 1
; 3B:       488D4E02         LEA RCX, [RSI+2]
; 3F:       458B544B01       MOV R10D, [R11+RCX*2+1]
; 44:       49D1E2           SHL R10, 1
; 47:       488BDA           MOV RBX, RDX
; 4A:       EB47             JMP L3
; 4C:       0F1F4000         NOP
; 50: L1:   418B7C5F01       MOV EDI, [R15+RBX*2+1]
; 55:       488D0C3F         LEA RCX, [RDI+RDI]
; 59:       8BF9             MOV EDI, ECX
; 5B:       81E7FE010000     AND EDI, 510
; 61:       8BD1             MOV EDX, ECX
; 63:       C1EA08           SHR EDX, 8
; 66:       81E2FE010000     AND EDX, 510
; 6C:       C1E910           SHR ECX, 16
; 6F:       81E1FE010000     AND ECX, 510
; 75:       85FF             TEST EDI, EDI
; 77:       7551             JNE L5
; 79:       F3410F10544801   MOVSS XMM2, [R8+RCX*2+1]
; 80:       F3410F105C5101   MOVSS XMM3, [R9+RDX*2+1]
; 87:       F30F59DA         MULSS XMM3, XMM2
; 8B:       F30F58CB         ADDSS XMM1, XMM3
; 8F: L2:   4883C302         ADD RBX, 2
; 93: L3:   41844424F8       TEST AL, [R12-8]                 ; safepoint
; 98:       4C39D3           CMP RBX, R10
; 9B:       7CB3             JL L1
; 9D:       F3410F10547601   MOVSS XMM2, [R14+RSI*2+1]
; A4:       F30F58D1         ADDSS XMM2, XMM1
; A8:       F3410F11547601   MOVSS [R14+RSI*2+1], XMM2
; AF:       4883C602         ADD RSI, 2
; B3: L4:   41844424F8       TEST AL, [R12-8]                 ; safepoint
; B8:       483B75F8         CMP RSI, [RBP-8]
; BC:       0F8C6EFFFFFF     JL L0
; C2:       BA17010120       MOV EDX, #x20010117              ; NIL
; C7:       C9               LEAVE
; C8:       F8               CLC
; C9:       C3               RET
; CA: L5:   F3410F10544801   MOVSS XMM2, [R8+RCX*2+1]
; D1:       F3410F105C5101   MOVSS XMM3, [R9+RDX*2+1]
; D8:       F30F59DA         MULSS XMM3, XMM2
; DC:       F30F5CCB         SUBSS XMM1, XMM3
; E0:       EBAD             JMP L2

A few things: (1) the double loop is actually a linear traversal where the outer loop variable increments the write index; this lets me avoid unpacking the write index from the access pattern, which saved like 4 instructions per product. (2) the variable acc plays the role of float x = 0.0 - it lets me avoid unnecessary writes. (3) the outer loop can be unrolled using a macro so that the inner loops occur sequentially with constant ranges. I'm putting that off for now since it might not be the best call.
The current form of this function is 20% faster than iterating over the access patterns, extracting indices, and computing ret[i] += arr1[j]*arr2[k]*(-1)^s for each pattern.

What SIMD instruction-sets do you care about optimizing for?  Can you use AVX2 for gathers (on hardware that's not crippled by microcode mitigations for security vulnerabilities)?  Or AArch64 with SVE gathers?  If not, there might still be some limited benefit from processing inputs for ret[i] and ret[i+1] in different halves of the same 128-bit vector, like x86 SSE movsd and movhps to manually gather 64-bit halves of a vector.

The (-1)^s term isn't actually computed. Instead, I just branch on the whether or not the last 8 bits are 0 - SIMD usually needs to be branchless, but in this case it's already better even for scalar to just left-shift that bit to the top and XOR it to flip the sign bit of a double (or not if it was 0).

use  some simd library like https://github.com/google/highway ;  it can help you to write code like 'a+b*c'  but run by simd instructions on many hardware platform (x86/arm/...)

How big is this array of access patterns?  How many times does it touch the same arr1[j] for a single ret[i]?  Is the range of j and k really only 4-bit, so the input arrays are quite small, like only 16 doubles each?  That's two AVX-512 vectors, so vpermi2pd zmm could select 8 desired elements from the entire arr1[0..15] range.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermi2w:vpermi2d:vpermi2q:vpermi2ps:vpermi2pd).  Can you group the + and - terms separately so the + terms can use fmadd while the - terms use fmsub?

@PeterCordes I don't know enough to answer, but I think that AVX (YMM registers, right?) is widely supported, so I can target it without much issue.

@PeterCordes The array of access patterns can be as long as ~130,000 elements. The largest range for i,j,k, etc. is one byte - so each of arr1, arr2, and ret always has at most 256 elements. Access patterns and lengths are generated and inserted into the code at compile time, so I never have to bounds check - all loops are for loops over constant ranges.

@PeterCordes I will assign the same ret[i] hundreds, maybe thousands, of times in the general case. When I take advantage of sparse representations, this number drops to one or two times, but sparsity is handled at the type level, not in this algorithm. This algorithm will occasionally need to handle the worst case.

@PeterCordes For a single ret[i], the algorithm will usually touch arr1[j] and arr2[j] once each, but there will be cases where it happens as many as 16 times.

@PeterCordes Yes, I can group the + terms and - terms separately.

Is it common to want to use the same access pattern (including filtering for sparseness) for multiple products?  It be worth JITing an instruction sequence with the load offsets baked into the machine code instead of getting loaded and unpacked separately.  Or if AVX2 gathers are usable, then maybe re-arrange your access-pattern data structure into just j and k indices, with res[i] indices implicit by position.  Like four j in a row followed by the corresponding four k in a row, for i+0-3.  You can load that with vpmovzxbd to get indices for vgatherdpd for vfmaddpd

But that works best if the number of products added to each res[i] is pretty similar (and same for subtractions if we keep those separate).  For some high outliers you could have a cleanup section I guess.  I feel like we don't have enough information about typical cases to suggest a good strategy.  Like you recompile this code for each different sparseness already or something?  Also as Soonts says, a lot of the savings could come from finding patterns that let you reuse some loads or do contiguous vector loads or broadcasts or shuffles.

Wait, your data is actually float?  Do you need the temporaries and/or res to be double to minimize rounding error, or can you use float throughout for twice as many elements per SIMD vector?  With double loading two halves of an XMM with movsd / movhps is a fairly efficient way to manually gather, but needing 4 elements to fill even an XMM vector means more shuffling.  Better if you're using AVX2 gathers, though, since per-instruction overhead is amortized over more elements.

@PeterCordes I've been getting away with floats. I should have said "float x = 0.0", etc. I'll fix it.

I think your algorithm going to bottleneck on memory load transactions. Most modern CPUs can only do 2 load transactions per cycle. Because you’re loading from random locations, you need 1 load for every loaded element. Your goal is saving these load transactions.
In the comments you wrote your access pattern array has 130k elements. This means to compute the complete thing, you need to load 260k elements from two input arrays, plus 130k integers from the access pattern table.
However, for 2 inputs of 256 elements each, there’re only 64k unique products of the input elements. Note a 2D array of 256×256 elements needs 512 kb of memory, which fits in CPU caches.
Think about splitting your algorithm in 2 steps.
On the first step, compute these 64k unique products. To implement it efficiently with AVX unroll by 4×16 blocks, this way you only need to load 64 vectors from the first array, 1k vectors from the second one, and store 16k vectors.
Then on the second step, for each element of the output vector you need to accumulate ±products[ i ] If you keep your access pattern in uint32_t will take 130k loads from temporary vector and 130k loads from the access pattern table.
Here’s an example how to implement second step without branches to apply the sign. The code is untested.
Compared to your algorithm, this method saves approximately 1/3 of memory loads.
// Increment or decrement acc by an element from source array
// Index to load the element is in bytes 1-2 of the packed integer
// The sign is in the lowest bit of that integer
inline void addSigned( __m128d& acc, const double* source, uint32_t packed )
{
    // Load element from the temporary buffer
    __m128d inc = _mm_load_sd( source + ( ( packed >> 8 ) & 0xFFFFu ) );

    // Make FP64 scalar with either 0.0 or -0.0 depending on the requested sign
    __m128i iv = _mm_cvtsi32_si128( packed & 1 );
    iv = _mm_slli_epi64( iv, 63 );

    // Conditionally negate the increment, and accumulate
    inc = _mm_xor_pd( inc, _mm_castsi128_pd( iv ) );
    acc = _mm_add_sd( acc, inc );
}

// Reduction table
const std::array<uint32_t, 130000> s_table;

void computeStuff( double* result, const double* productsMatrix )
{
    // Assuming the table is sparse, fill output vector with zeros
    const __m256d zero = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 0x100; i += 4 )
        _mm256_storeu_pd( result + i, zero );

    uint32_t destElement = 0x100;
    __m128d acc = _mm_setzero_pd();

    for( uint32_t packed : s_table )
    {
        const uint32_t rdi = packed >> 24;
        if( rdi != destElement )
        {
            if( destElement < 0x100 )
                _mm_store_sd( result + destElement, acc );
            acc = _mm_setzero_pd();
            destElement = rdi;
        }

        addSigned( acc, productsMatrix, packed );
    }

    if( destElement < 0x100 )
        _mm_store_sd( result + destElement, acc );
}

Another idea, write a tool to compile your access pattern table into a reasonably efficient AVX C++ source code. By reasonably efficient, I mean use full-vector loads when possible, and reuse loaded elements to compute multiple output values.
Unfortunately, if your access pattern is truly random, the generated function will be too long, will bottleneck on instruction fetch and decode. If however your access pattern is not truly random and you can abuse symmetry, cyclic permutations of input vectors, or similar tricks to split your algorithm into multiple calls of the same function processing different data, the approach might help.

Most of the access patterns will follow a general rule: when the first read index increase, the second read index decreases. This is a little broken because of the non-orthogonal metric, meaning there are often "unexpected" contributions to a coefficient. The maximum size for both input arrays and for the output array is 256 elements (floats). It's possible for a coefficient of the returned array to depend on every coefficient of both argument arrays, but this is not the norm.

@MonadMania: In that case, to get 8 floats that go with the same ret[i], you could _mm256_loadu_ps from both arrays and _mm256_permutexvar_ps one of the load results to reverse the elements in it, then _mm256_fmadd_ps.  But that gives you 8 products for the same ret[i] in one vector, when you'd rather have products for ret[i + 0..7] so you don't have to horizontally sum them.  (Although that would be done outside the loop so isn't a total disaster.)
